# how to replace list of elements in an array with index value, if element has specific prefix of Xyz in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, prefix

how to replace list of elements in an array with an index value, if the element has a specific prefix of Xyz in javascript.
I need to find the items in an array that has john as a prefix and replace them with the index values. note: only string with a prefix of xyz is valid
for example
input:
arrNames[john, jack, johnsmith, funjack, john].
output: [john,jack,2,funjack,john]

I tried with the indexOf method but didn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is your goal

```
const arrNames=['john', 'jack', 'johnsmith', 'funjack', 'john'];

arrNames.map(x => x.startsWith('john') && x !== 'john' ? arrNames.findIndex(f => f===x):x)
```